# How to make prevent public key inside jar to be saved using Java code

Tags: java, security, jar, certificate, digital-certificate

After signing a jar , we can retrieve the public keys from jar using

```
Certificate[] cert = jarentry.getCertificates();
```

Once certificate is extracted we can save this to a new keystore as trusted cert.

Once this is done , then second user can sign any jar using this certificate , isn't ?

I want to distribute content as jars , contents will contain properties files for a application init.

I want to make sure  that an user is not capable to rebuilding the property files using the certificate he extracted from jarentry.

In the code which reads the jar contents i am checking that jar is signed with my certificate only and also checking that jar is not tampered with .

But the issue came to my mind that if I am able to extract the certificate from jar then why don;t a third guy ?

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

> Once this is done , then second user can sign any jar using this certificate , isn't ?

No, you need the **private** key to be able to sign a JAR. You can't sign a JAR with just the public key. Ofcourse the private key is not in the certificate.

See [Signing and Verifying JAR Files](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html) in Sun's Java Tutorials, it explains the principles and how to do it in detail.

Comment: yea :) , thanks jesper , i try to sign with the certificate and it failed. You need a private key to sign jar .........